# How do I correctly insert images in LaTeX files?

Tags: graphics

My relevant lines of code are:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,graphicx,epstopdf}
...
\begin{document}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.gif,.jpg}
...
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{EncodingMethod}
\caption{Encoding Method}
\end{figure}
```

and all I get out of this block of code is:

[image]

Comment: Show the options you give to `\documentclass`. Having `draft` in there will do this.

Comment: ah, I do have draft in my options for \documentclass, I will try removing this. (edit) Thank you, This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the expected behavior if you pass the `draft` option to `\documentclass`. Simply removing it should fix it.

Note that `draft` not only displays boxes for pictures (so the document compiles faster), but it also adds little black boxes on the margin to indicate overfullness. This can be useful information when improving hyphenation with extra hints or to tweak picture sizes.

Comment: oh, I was wondering about those black boxes at the end of some lines to. I always got around it by adding `\newline` before the word that caused it.

Comment: You shouldn't mess with the line breaking just to get overfull boxes to disappear! This will mess up automatic reflowing. Instead give LaTeX hyphenation hints on where words can be broken, e.g. `Donau\-schiff\-fahrts\-ge\-sell\-schaft`. Also make sure you set the correct language for your document so the correct hyphenation rules are picked (the default is some English).

Comment: If you wish to have `draft` on the documentclass, then you can override this option for `graphicx`, and so include the images, either by `\usepackage[final]{graphicx}` or by `\setkeys{Gin}{draft=false}` after the `\usepackage{graphicx}`.